# How to encode the extra latin1 characters in smpp?

Tags: javascript, encoding, iso-8859-1, smpp

How are characters in latin-1 encoded in submit_sm or deliver_sm in the case of extended characters?
Like: ¶ µ ÷

Is there a proper way to convert a string to latin-1 characters?

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using an SMS splitter code & altered it to fit latin-1 characters:
https://cs.stanford.edu/people/miles/iso8859.html#ISO

And it only has 140 char compared to 160 GSM, so be mindful when using. 
It'll differ for each problem, but for mine, I couldn't find an existing solution.